# correct usage of setCellValueFactory

Tags: java, javafx, tablecolumn

I am trying to do the following:

```
tableColumns[0].setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<DiaryEntry,String>("username")
    );    
tableColumns[1].setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<DiaryEntry,Project>("project")
    );
```

So the first one works perfectly fine. It uses the getUsername() Method in my class "DiaryEntry" in order to the Display the String. The second one is using the Method getProject() and tries to add the Project to my table. When doing that I end up with something like "2xProject2353asxk". This makes perfectly sense, since it can not simply display the Project object in the table.

In my Class Project I have a getter "getName()". So my Question here is: Is there any way I can change my second Statement, so that the table will enter the Project's name? I read a couple of threads about the setCellValueFactory() Method, but I still can't figure a solution out.

Comment: Can you show the **exact** output rather than "something like..."?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Well presumably it would be different for different cells...

Comment: That is fine. I am just looking for a more precise example.

Comment: Sure, one precise Example for the Output would be: diary.Project@2632ae5b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `cellFactory` in addition to the `cellValueFactory`

```
tableColumns[1].setCellValueFactory(
    new PropertyValueFactory<DiaryEntry,Project>("project")
);
tableColumns[1].setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<DiaryEntry, Project>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Project project, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(project, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setText(project.getName());
        }
    }
});
```

The `cellValueFactory` tells the column *what value* to display in its cells; the `cellFactory` tells it *how* to display the value.

Comment: That works flawless and now I understand how to even do it in other cases. Thank you.